# How to make the page show the international characters correctly without breaking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this strange character problem, even the page is set to use utf-8

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
<script> 
    $("#smsto,#offlinesmsto").intlTelInput({
    autoHideDialCode: false,
    defaultCountry: "be",
    utilsScript: "js/utils.js"
  });
```

How to resolve the broken characters please? 
i am using this plugin: https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input

[image]

Comment: The problem appears to be in the plugin you are using. At least the problem cannot be reconstructed using only the code included in the question. Consider using the bug reporting tools of the plugin site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntlTelInput.js was broken in IDE (Netbeans) as a result it failed.

[image]

Hope this info, help others